# UserControl as a TabItem

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I've been playing with WPF and I'm not sure what I'm trying to do is possible. So is it possible to have a usercontrol describing a tabitem? I've tried but without success.

Right now I use user controls for the content but I would like to change that to be more generic.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do, can you be more specific?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can:

1) Place a `UserControl` inside a `TabItem`:

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem>
        <local:MyUserControl/>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

2) Inherit from `TabItem` rather than `UserControl`:

```
public class MyTabItem : TabItem { ... }

<TabControl>
    <local:MyTabItem/>
</TabControl>
```

Comment: Note that with the second option, automatic type-based styling of your `TabItem` won't occur, because WPF doesn't automatically apply styles to derived types.